# How do you write a askubuntu username backwards?

Tags: support

I recently saw a username on ask ubuntu where half of it was written backwards.
How is that possible?!

Comment: ‮‮A Backwards Username?

Comment: Then there is [ben is uǝq backwards](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/179419/ben-is-ueq-backwards).. I don't know how to do it, but it's just a character.

Comment: @mateo_salta: That is freaking awesome.. How did you manage to trick Stack Exchange's Comment System????

Comment: @Aditya That is the beauty of U+202e.

Comment: @Seth Incorrect. *That* is not a single character but in fact a very fancy usage of [various UTF characters that look like a mirrored version of real characters](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down-map.htm).

Comment: (‮‮(@FEichinger Testing... Did I succeed... Looks like I did... Thanks... @mateo as well

Comment: ‮I don't know, but I do know that this is normal on my planet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many such tools on the internet, that consist of using normal text characters to make it "look" like the text it reversed or upside down.

One such one I found here - http://textmechanic.co/Reverse-Text-Generator.html
Hit the "Upside Down" button

For example my user name would look like this:

ɐʇןɐs‾oǝʇɐɯ

An even better one is this - http://www.sherv.net/flip.html

˙noʎ ǝɹɐ ʍoɥ

You can then put this text in your username by changing it in your profile, click on your username the "edit" on the main site.

[image]

tђเร เร ς๏๏l!

Comment: łı£§!!! æ↓↑ Ł¡«§!!!

Comment: Great answer. For future members, TextMechanic moved from textmechanic.com to [textmechanic.co](http://textmechanic.co) though.

Comment: Cool, thanks I put that change in :)

Comment: **Reminder:** username changes are only permitted _once per 30 days_.

Answer (score 7):

## Writing backwards

Writing backwards, as in the characters being arranged in reversed order (ex. below) is achieved through use of the `U+202E` character, aka `RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE`. This is used to force right-to-left writing, mostly for languages that are written RTL (although HTML & CSS nowdays support various ways of achieving that without use of `U+202E`.

> **Example**
> ... nuf si sdrawkcab gnitirW

*Please note that this example does **not** use U+202E, but only emulates the results.*

Doing this has various side-effects. Mostly, it breaks some parts of the layout, as it is an *override* and as such also affects other text and HTML on the same or deeper levels when it is invoked.

## Writing inverted

Writing inverted, as in the characters being flipped upside-down and then mirrored on the vertical axis (ex. below) is achieved through use of [various UTF characters](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down-map.htm) that resemble a "normal" character manipulated this way.

> **Example**
> ǝɯosǝʍɐ sı ƃuıʇıɹʍ pǝʇɹǝʌuı ʇnq ˙˙˙

Answer (score 2):

˙˙˙oɹq ʇnoqɐ ƃuıʞʃɐʇ ǝɹ,noʎ ʇɐɥʍ ǝnʃɔ ou ǝʌɐɥ I‮

http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down.htm

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to [ObsessiveSSOℲ](https://askubuntu.com/users/54298/obsessivesso) who is using unicode to make text "appear" upsidedown. It's not a feature of the site at all and can be done on any site.

Comment: but how do you do that?

Comment: I don't normally do this, but you should really use a search engine "How do I write text backwards"

Comment: Oops. I wasn't thinking :$

Comment: "...and can be done on any site." Any site that properly handles multibyte character sets, that is :P